# Verify signup via SMS?

Tags: signup, sms

Does anybody know of a plugin available for WordPress that would require a new user to enter their mobile phone number as part of the sign up process?

The user would then be sent a verification code via SMS which they would have to enter to complete the sign up process.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) + [Gravity Forms User Registration Add-On](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/) + [Gravity Forms Twilio SMS Add-On](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/twilio/) can help you imo.

Comment: This should be exactly what you are looking for. [Word Press SMS Verification Plugin](http://www.cs-networks.net/index.php/products/toolsandutils/wordpress-sms-verification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these resources:

- http://www.marketingtechblog.com/wordpress/wordpress-sms-mobile-alert-subscriptio/
- http://www.bulksms.com/int/docs/eapi/third_party_api/
- http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/

The concept behind this would be to send a randomly generated string to the mobile phone number that the user enters, store it as a transient, and ask the user to enter it to send him his/her password via e-mail.

`wp-login.php?action=register` already does half of the job - sending he password to the registered person, you would only have to stop lay this process off until the password from the SMS is provided.

So an options would be:

1. User registers, entering his phone number along with his e-mail
2. E-mail with random password is not sent
3. Random code is generated and sent using any SMS gateway API and stored in transients along with the user ID
4. User enters code and any pending transients matching that code and user ID will release the registration e-mail with the password

Alternatively you can:

1. Stop e-mail from going out with the password
2. Send password through SMS gateway instead

The second option is very very simple, most gateways provide PHP libraries that you can use to interface with the API, override the `wp_mail()` pluggable to send the password through the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this would require a third party text service. Theses are not normally free. We have used http://www.txtlocal.co.uk/ before for sending / receiving texts but I've not heard of any plugin that would offer that for you.